# SQL: retrieve first updates on date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a history table which I want to use to retrieve some data. The table has only a couple of columns:

- Country
- questionID
- Date change
- Old value
- New value

Country always stays the same, but there are multiple values that can be changed, which means that if on 2020-01-01 12:00 multiple values are changed in Kosovo, multiple rows are created with the same datetime. Ie:

- Kosovo
- 123
- 2020-01-01 12:00
- 100 employees
- 101 employees

---

- Kosovo
- 234
- 2020-01-01 12:00
- 14 acres
- 15 acres

I want to add an additional column in my query that returns the count of which update it is on a certain data. I.e.; the update done at 12:00 is update #1 for all rows, but the update done afterwards at 12:30, is update #2 for all rows in Kosovo on 2020-01-01.

I hope this makes sense, but I can't figure it out. I can partition on row level, but that means that each row gets it's own number. I want the number to be similar across all rows updated at the same time, so all rows updated at 12:00 get row #1, all at 12:30 get #2..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK`:

```
select t.*, DENSE_RANK() over (partition by country order by datechange) as new_col
from test t
```

Output:

```
Country     DateChange           new_col
Kosovo  2020-01-01 12:00:00.000    1
Kosovo  2020-01-01 12:00:00.000    1
Kosovo  2020-01-01 12:00:00.000    1
Kosovo  2020-01-01 12:00:00.000    1
Kosovo  2020-01-01 12:00:00.000    1
Kosovo  2020-01-01 12:30:00.000    2
Kosovo  2020-01-01 12:30:00.000    2
Kosovo  2020-01-01 12:30:00.000    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by country order by datechange) as update_no
from table t
```